# Changing fonts depending on the major mode

Tags: emacs, fonts, major-mode

Is there are way to change the fonts depending on the major mode? If so, how? I usually use a proportional font, but only for dired mode and shell mode, I want to switch to a non-proportional font. These modes do not have a special face for them, and just use the default face, so it cannot be just done by setting the font faces. I want to be able to automatically switch depending on the major mode, perhaps using hooks.

Comment: Using `mode-hooks` will be difficult because fonts will change for all buffers. See http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts. There is no `switch-buffer-hook`; see http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the mode hook, hooking your function that remaps the face for the current buffer using the [face remapping feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html):

```
(defun use-monospace ()
  "Switch the current buffer to a monospace font."
  (face-remap-add-relative 'default '(:family "Monospace")))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'use-monospace)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to defining your own function as above, is to use `buffer-face-mode`.  Normally this will use `variable-pitch` for buffers it is enabled in, but since you want to use a variable pitch font as the default you can change it to `fixed-pitch` instead:

```
(setq buffer-face-mode-face 'fixed-pitch)
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'buffer-face-mode)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'buffer-face-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks, this also looks helpful.